# ssmtp root alias doesn't work

Tags: email, email-server, ssmtp, aliases

my ssmtp doesn't change "To" from 'root' to my email.

In my ssmtp.conf I have: `root=servers@latina.com`

In debug output I found only one difference between working and not working commands:

working command: *echo "body" | mail -s "test" servers@latina.com*

**debug output:**

```
Feb 16 13:28:20 deb1-sh sSMTP[21160]: To: servers@latina.com
```

not working command: *echo "body" | mail -s "test" root*

**debug output:**

```
Feb 16 13:27:21 deb1-sh sSMTP[21151]: To: root
```

According to this post:http://possiblelossofprecision.net/?p=591 I tried to add file /etc/mail.rc with following content:

```
alias root servers@latina.com
```

With no success.

I run debian jessie 8.3.

It looks like ssmtp root alias doesn't work. Has anybody idea why? Or how to solve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: I'm suffering from the same issue. `ssmtp root` works (mail is sent to the address specified in ssmtp.conf root=... line), but at the same time `mail root` does not work. The latter call generates an error in `/var/log/mail.err` ("553 5.1.8 Domain name required: <root@>") that indicates that the To-address was not re-written. I have confirmed that `mail` actually reads the `/etc/mail.rc` file on my system using `strace`.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, the `root` configuration setting for sSMTP is *only* used for *local accounts* so should be set to a username that’s valid for the local host. It’s not an alias like those used by other more fully-featured MTAs (which can be used to forward mail to another domain).

The comments in my `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` state

> (5) root
>
> If sSMTP finds an unqualified e-mail address among
> the recipients, and it corresponds to a username on your local
> machine with a userid less than 1000, then the e-mail is sent to
> this value instead.  The idea is that mail sent to 'root' should
> probably go to 'postmaster' instead.

Answer (score 0):

ssmtp does not replace mail. I got it working by using ssmtp binary instead of mail.mailutils. You can test it by running this command:

`MAIL=$(which mail) mv "${MAIL}" "${MAIL}.orig" && ln -s $(which ssmtp) "${MAIL}"`